# Internal Server Error with POST using XML on Postman

Tags: java, api, post, jersey, postman

I've came upon a problem and I am struggling for 5 hours.
I've created a Java API (right now just for testing) in Eclipse using Jersey and this is my first time creating an API.

I am using Postman to test it.

When calling the GET method to just return a string "Hello" it's working great.

The problem is when I try the POST method that accepts an object of a class Person as an input parameter and also just returns string "Hello" I get Internal Server Error. I know I am not using the Person object right now, but I am just testing the input parameter from Postman and it's not working.
I tried to change the function in the API to be without an input parameter and just to be POST and it works like that, it prints the "Hello", but I need that input parameter for later...
The problem is somewhere around the creation of the object in the xml code in Postman maybe, I don't know.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Here is the code for the API with the methods get and post

```
@Path("/employee")
public class API {
    
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        @Path("/examplepost")
        public String examplePost(Person p) {
            return "Hello";
        }
        
        @GET
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        @Path("/exampleget")
        public String exampleGet() {
            return "Hello";
        }
}
```

This is the Person class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public Person(String name, int age, int id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return id+"::"+name+"::"+age;
    }

}
```

And these are the results from Postman

[GET Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLptF.png)

[POST Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsCfP.png)

Comment: Try adding @RequestBody in the post method argument: public String examplePost(@RequestBody Person p)

Comment: @aang13 I tried doing that but i get an error "RequestBody cannot be resolved to a type", and there are no imports for it

Comment: try importing this import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

Comment: @aang13 that is not resolved as well, I am not using Spring in my project, I've never 
 worked with Spring, I just have Jersey here from a tutorial I found on yt, but apparently they do not have this problem.

Comment: Can you check you logs for any warnings with the word JAXBContext in it.

Comment: @aang13 I recreated my project using Spring Boot and now it's working as it was supposed to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the argument `Person p` does not have the right class type. the function is consuming an XML not an instance of Person. So you have to use [JAXBElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html) that represents information about an Xml Element

```
public String examplePost(JAXBElement<Person> p) {
        Person person = p.getValue();
        return "Hello";
}
```

[OPTIONAL] Also in PostMan: you have to specify what data you are sending by adding the xml version at the beginning

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person>
    <!-- Person's attributes -->
</Person>
```

Comment: This is definitely not required. Person _is_ allowed if all is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my issue using Spring Boot and @RequestBody, all is well